# Can a Half-Orc's Relentless Endurance trait save it from its soul being stolen when it dies?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, racial-traits, character-death, half-orc

[Half-Orcs](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/half-orc) have the [Relentless Endurance racial trait](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/half-orc#Half-OrcTraits):

> ***Relentless Endurance.*** When you are reduced to 0 hit points but not killed outright, you can drop to 1 hit point instead. You can't use this feature again until you finish a long rest.

So what happens if a Half-Orc is directed by an effect that steals its soul if it dies, such as (but not limited to) *soul cage*?

The description of [*soul cage*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/soul-cage) says:

> This spell snatches the soul of a humanoid as it dies and traps it inside the tiny cage you use for the material component.

If the Half-Orc dies, then this spell could be used as a reaction. If the Half-Orc dies, what would happen first? Would the *soul cage* steal the soul, or would the Relentless Endurance happen first and the Half-Orc would remain alive?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

#### Relentless Endurance does not trigger if you die.

Relentless Endurance states:

> When you are *reduced to 0 hit points but not killed outright*, you can drop to 1 hit point instead. You can’t use this feature again until you finish a long rest.

*Soul cage* has a casting time of 1 Reaction:

> which you take when a humanoid you can see within 60 feet of you *dies*

If you are using Relentless Endurance, at no point are you dead, so at no point are you an eligible target for *soul cage*. If you are dead, then you can't use Relentless Endurance, and would be an eligible target for *soul cage*.

*Soul cage* only works when a humanoid *dies*, Relentless Endurance only triggers when you *don't die*, so there is no interaction between these two features.

To answer the question directly, Relentless Endurance can indirectly protect you from *soul cage* by possibly delaying your death, as instead of being knocked unconscious and rolling death saves when you reach 0 hit points, you instead have 1 hit point.

Comment: But that's like saying a Constitution of 16 more more protects you from it (since you are less likely to die). When people say protects they mean directly protects.

Comment: I don't disagree with the Answer. However, isn't there a variation in the rules where 0 HP causes immediate death? Could the Asker be playing in such a game?

Comment: @trlkly I think the variant you are thinking of is the rule for NPC creature. The default is that an NPC creaure die immediately upon reaching 0 hitpoints, but the DM can optionally allow an NPC to make death saves instead.

Comment: Does this mean you have an answers, @Mołot? Anything you put helps.

Comment: @MikeZ. I included Molot's input in my last statement. Relentless Endurance can protect you from Soul Cage, in the sense that it can delay your becoming an eligible target for the spell.

Comment: Oh, sorry @ThomasMarkov, I didn't see the answer change.